# Increase space between two directories from “ls”

Tags: bash, iterm

I recently switched to Mac from Ubuntu and I've still had a quite a lot to figure out.

For iTerm2, how to adjust the space between files/directories? The following screenshot shows what it looks like after I did "ls". As you can see, the two directories "mathematica" and "python" are very close;

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The columns are equal sizes, it's just that the word is longer and therefore uses more of the column width. It is not possible to change the column width.

To print ls in a single column, run `ls -l`.

Comment: *Perfect* answer. I have only this to add ;-) regarding "I recently switched to Mac from Ubuntu and I've still had a quite a lot to figure out." It is unfortunate that you were incorrectly taught about UNIX by beginning with Linux. [1977](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) came long before [1991](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux). BSD exists, and is free and freely distributable under the BSD License, because 
[System V}(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V#Rivalry_with_BSD)was NOT and very expensive. (continues ----->)

Comment: The UNIX Wars are over… yet Linus single-handedly created yet another rivalry, and did so by selfishly and arbitrarily creating differences between Linux and the other UNIXs. The way Linux works in how it differs from *real* UNIX is entirely arbitrary and unnecesary. Linux is a great OS now, stable, secure, and OSS. But @BlueFeet, don't get annoyed at BSD or OS X. Get annoyed at Linus/Linux for teaching you "bad things," like how to be lazy, and expecting things to work a certain way that work *no where else that way.*

Comment: FWIW Linux Torvald is a great man, has done great things, is as important as any other of the *Greats* in software technology, even if he did them clearly *wrong,* and caused you and many others this kind of *pain.* Linux is so influential now that no one even notices that *Linux* is NOT an operating system! It is a  "just" a kernel. The OS is GNU! That alone shows how ridiculous penguinistas are, if there are any left. (Most admins are now OS agnostic... they no longer care what the OS is, if they are pros)

Comment: @chillin In this case it is not Linus fault. It is not the kernel which differs it is the userspace code which for Linux is GNU. So the commands that differ are GNU rather than BSD. Blame Richard Stallman not Linus for this :)

Answer (score 1):

`COLUMNS=80 CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -C | sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/&    /g'`

- `COLUMNS=80`: set column width to 80 characters, which should be less than normal width for new spaces
- `CLICOLOR_FORCE=1`: enable color after sed
- `ls -C`: `ls` with force multi-column output
- `sed -E`: `sed` with extended (modern) regular expressions to enable `+` in regex
- `'s/[[:space:]]+/&    /g'`: find spaces and replace with matched string + 4 more spaces